# How to refer to page range of included PDF

Tags: pdfpages

I included a multi page PDF in my document like this:

```
\begin{flushleft}                                                                                                           
\textlabel{Annexure 5}{email}: Email exchange                                                                                                                                                
\end{flushleft}                                                                                                             
\includepdf[pages={1-},scale=0.75]{email.pdf}
```

The PDF spans multiple pages. I want to refer to the page range occupied by the
PDF. With \pageref{email} I get only the starting page.

Answer (score 0):

To reference the page range occupied by the multi-page PDF, you can use the `\label` and `\pageref` commands in the following way:

```
\begin{flushleft}
\textlabel{Annexure 5}{email}: Email exchange (\pageref{email}-\pageref{emailend})
\end{flushleft}
\includepdf[pages={1-},scale=0.75]{email.pdf}
\label{emailend}
```

The `\label` command creates a reference point for the PDF with the name "email". The `\pageref` command retrieves the page number of the reference point. The `\label` command at the end of the PDF creates another reference point with the name "emailend". The `\pageref` command retrieves the page number of this reference point. Finally, the difference between the two page numbers is calculated, and the page range is displayed in the text.

Comment: emailend gives the page number of the next page not the last page of the PDF.

Comment: Also, `\textlabel` is defined how? And where is the label for `email` set? If it is set beforehand, it will give the page before the first page of the PDF. And there's no calculation involved here, is there?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to use the following literally, but it demonstrates a method which works. I don't use this exactly, but I use something a little bit similar fairly regularly, in that I get the total pages from `\pdfximage{}` and `\pdflastximagepages`. When I first investigated this, I couldn't find a high-level interface, so this uses something from pdfTeX. As such, it may or may not work with other engines.

Basically, this uses `pagecommand` to set a label for the first page. `\pdfximage` is added to this value less one. This is used to set a custom counter. The value of this counter is then compared to the page counter on every subsequent page of the PDF and the end label set if it matches. This can then be cross-referenced. It should be possible to avoid the need for setting the second label at all, but I couldn't get that to work because I couldn't figure out how to recover the value of the first page of the PDF in an expandable way without more seriously abusing standard LaTeX.

Ideally, `pdfpages` would provide a simple key-value interface for setting a label on the first and last pages, but it doesn't, even though it is clearly retrieving the same kind of information from the engine. Hence my reinvention of the wheel in inconveniently square format ....

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-email.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  1\par
  \clearpage
  2\par
  \clearpage
  3\par
  \clearpage
  4
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\newcounter {mypdfcounter}
\setcounter {mypdfcounter} {0}
\newcommand \textlabel[2]{#2}% no idea what this is meant to do or how it is meant to be defined
\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}                                                                                                           
  \textlabel{Annexure 5}{email}: Email exchange \pageref{pdf:email}--\pageref{pdf:email2}                                                                                                                                        
\end{flushleft}     
\pdfximage {\jobname-email.pdf}
\def \makethispdfpagestyle{\setcounter{mypdfcounter}{\thepage}\addtocounter{mypdfcounter}{-1}\addtocounter{mypdfcounter}{\pdflastximagepages}\label{pdf:email}}
\makeatletter
\def \makenextpdfpagestyle{\ifnum\c@page=\c@mypdfcounter\label{pdf:email2}\fi}
\makeatother
\def \makepdfpagestyle{%
  \makethispdfpagestyle
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \global\let\makethispdfpagestyle\makenextpdfpagestyle
}
\includepdf[pages={1-},scale=0.75,pagecommand=\makepdfpagestyle]{\jobname-email} 


\end{document}
```

[image: cross-reference first and last page of PDF]

Note that I have no idea what `\textlabel{}{}` is meant to do or how you have implemented a reference to the first page of the PDF since this is not automatic unless you're adding to a list-of-list. Since you don't provide any code for any of that, I assumed nothing for the latter and made up something implausibly simple for the former. Whether any of your actual stuff works with the code in this answer is anybody's guess, but nobody but yours to know.